# 'BlockNode' object has no attribute 'context'

Tags: python, django, django-endless-pagination

I am new to django/python. I am trying out Pagination on scroll using django-endless-pagination and found the below error: `'BlockNode' object has no attribute 'context'`

`entry_index.html`

```
<h2>Logs:</h2>
{% include page_template %}
{% block js %}
{{ block.super }}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
<script>
    $.endlessPaginate({
        paginateOnScroll: true,
        paginateOnScrollChunkSize: 5
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

`entry_index_page.html`

```
{% for i in list %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am following [Django Endless Pagination](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html#pagination-on-scroll) tutorial for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show the entire html ?

Comment: @karthikr - Updated the question above with entire html.

Comment: Are you not `extend`ing this template from anywhere? If no, remove `{{ block.super }}`

Answer (score 4):

```
{% include page_template %}
    {% block js %}
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
        <script>$.endlessPaginate();</script>
    {% endblock %}
```

I used code like this in template instead of code shown in below.. Then it worked...

```
{% include page_template %}
{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>
    <script>$.endlessPaginate();</script>
{% endblock %}
```