# KeyError at / u'request' when trying to set up django endless-pagination

Tags: ajax, django

I'm getting KeyError at /  u'request' when trying to set up django endless-pagination in py project

In template /home/user/Documents/poster/poster/templates/index.html, error at line 22

```
{% paginate group %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this

If you follow endless-pagination manual you have to split your template in 2 parts as said in tutorial

First template - that one which is main

Second template - what ajax should load to your main page.

Problem was in main template - you should get rid of this line

```
{{ block.super }}
```

And everything will work.

Thanks to this post
['BlockNode' object has no attribute 'context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143589/blocknode-object-has-no-attribute-context)
which helped me to figure out what is going on.